# How to make tar.xz extraction fast?

Tags: zip, extract

This is System's current extraction speed 193.2kB/sec. How can I make it fast?

I have an SSD, i7 8th Gen, RTX 2060, and on an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop

Actions Taken: Downloads Tab -> Right Click on Zip -> Extract Here

[image]

Comment: What is the exact command or action you are using for extraction? Where do the zipped and the target file reside? Do you see a CPU bottleneck during this operation? Or is it due to slow disk IO?

Comment: @FedKad I'll give more info, I will check it.

Comment: Action is Right Click - Extract Here ||

Zip is on "Downloads" ||

It seems not bottleneck ||

I have an SSD ||

Did I answer your questions correctly @FedKad?

Comment: If there is a lot of small (tiny) files contained in the `.tar` file, that can make a difference in how fast the speed goes.  Larger files will transfer faster than a bunch of tiny files will.  It has to do with the buffering of the files.  Each new file that is getting extracted starts a new buffer.

Comment: Compressing a ***single*** 56MB file into a `.tar.xz` file takes almost 20 seconds on my system. However, (after clearing the file cache) decompressing that file using the Nautilus' Extract menu option works almost instantaneously. However, please note the previous commenter. Please, [edit] your question and add the extra information _plus_ the number of files & directories in the `.tar.xz` file.

Comment: What did you do to troubleshoot the issue? Did you try compressing and extracting other tar.xz files for comparison? Did you try using the `tar` command from the terminal? Please do some troubleshooting steps, and report the results.

Answer (score 1):

**@Terrance** answered my question

"If there are a lot of small (tiny) files contained in the .tar file, that can make a difference in how fast the speed goes. Larger files will transfer faster than a bunch of tiny files will. It has to do with the buffering of the files. Each new file that is getting extracted starts a new buffer."

**To make sure that his answer is correct:** (I'm new to Ubuntu and I know my Windows 11 OS in terms of extraction speed that's why use it to compare) I tried to unzip the same file on my Windows 11 OS, and yes, it's similar to the extraction speed on my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop

Again, thanks man @Terrance for answering my question, Cheers!